# How do you run Rest assured against a test database?

Tags: java, unit-testing, rest, jakarta-ee, rest-assured

I am using Rest assured and I wonder how I can change the database it is run against?

Currently I am testing against my application which connects to the database that holds all my data, however it is slow. I want Rest assured to use my test database. How can I do that? Do I need to use a second server that connects only to a database with only some of my data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

db tests are slow. period. network tests (over http) are also slow. first of all: what do you want to do? if we are talking about unit testing then you are doing it wrong. in unit tests you shouldn't test everything from json over http to db. try to avoid both. if you framework stack supports it (e.g. spring-mvc) you can test your json bindings without https traffic. if not, separate http binding tests from business logic (mock your services). same with database. test only your dao/repository without anything else.

when you have many small tests you can easily separate slower (network, db, integration smoke test) from fast (business logic) and put them in different groups. then you can also selectively run only specific group (depending which part you are changing at the moment). also on jenkins you can have separated stages for each group. this way you will quick feedback from your ci if you business logic fails and if they pass then jenkins will perform also slower tests

if for any reason you don't want to make your tests smaller then consider connecting to db only once (before your tests) and not closing this connection. this will speed up running all tests in total. if your test changes db content try to keep it as a single transaction and do rollback after test. this way you will avoid setting up db before each test

Comment: So you mean that slower tests are run by Jenkins and unit testing in developing stage?

Comment: almost: jenkins should run every possible tests, for all databases, browsers, integration, unit tests etc. everything. if you split them in groups, on average you will get error message earlier. also you can spread different groups on different machines and run them in parallel. developer should run tests that he thinks are necessary. i run all quick tests during almost every ctrl+s and db tests just before push to origin

Comment: REST Assured actually has support for Spring MVC as well with the new spring-mock-mvc module.

Comment: In my experience Rest assured tests seem to run about twice as slow as they need to regardless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a database for tests, use a embedded-database ([h2](http://www.h2database.com) in memory for instance).

In you config.xml :

```
<beans>

    ....
    <!-- override your datasource bean named myDataSource -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="myDataSource">
         <!-- sql script with create tables -->
        <jdbc:script location="init_database.sql"/>
         <!-- sql script with insert -->
        <jdbc:script location="seed_database.sql"/>
    </jdbc:initialize-database>  
</beans>
```